# Hide All Users @ Logon in 13.10

Tags: 13.04, login, login-screen

I'm setting up a laptop with Ubuntu 13.04 and my plan is to put it on our domain. I already have it connected to the domain, I just need to figure out how to change the logon page so all it displays is a Username and Password entry box.

I know this can be done in earlier versions of Ubuntu, but those methods do not appear to work in this instance. Does anyone know if the process has changed?

Comment: The answer is in this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/361176/15811  `minimum-uid=500` set this to `9999` and all userids<9999 will not show up/

Comment: @Rinzwind I suggest you re-read his question.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121124/how-do-i-enable-the-other-user-for-login-with-active-directory

Comment: If you find a suitable answer (and it's not a duplicate), please  see http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mattfischer.com/blog/?p=343

I found this blog article that helped explain everything I was looking to do. 
Hopefully it helps someone else.